# timezone error reading csv

Tags: r, timezone, readr

After googling for a couple of hours I have not found a solution to this problem.
Basically when I run `read_csv("some_file.csv")` function from `readr` package I get the following error:

> Error: Unknown TZ UTC

and csv is not read.

The only way I can read the CSV is this way:

```
read_csv("some_file.csv",locale=locale(tz="Australia/Sydney"))
```

Sydney being my timezone.

But I'd rather fix the error than work around it if possible.
Does anybody know how to fix the UTC error permanently? E.g. Startup instructions?
Ta.

Answer (score 5):

the `locale` input argument is set to `default_locale()`. When you print out the `default_locale` function, you can see that it read in the locale from `options`.

To set the locale permanently so that it is set every time you start R, you can add the following line to your ~PATH_TO_R~/etc/Rprofile.site

```
options(readr.default_locale=readr::locale(tz="Australia/Sydney"))
```

For temporary solution, just add this line at the top of your script

Comment: Thanks Chinsoon. I've updated my Rprofile.site file. Actually working back from where the default_locale function is so obvious. This approach will save me many a headache in the future. Thanks.